# SUM(value) where {date filter) is in an aggregation query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, temp-tables

I am doing an aggregation query for a temp table ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741835/create-a-temp-table-with-a-distinct-name-and-sum-of-values)) and need to filter the sum part on a date range.

The query I have is:

```
insert @temp2(name, cost) 
    select ename6, sum(dqr.cost)
    from dbo.condensed7day_query_result dqr
    group by dqr.ename6;
```

However, I need the sum(dqr.cost) to actually be

```
sum(dqr.cost) (dbo.condensed7day_query_result.start_date >= @StartDate) and (dbo.condensed7day_query_result.start_date <= @EndDate)
```

And if the `sum()` is a `null` (no rows returned), I'd prefer it be a 0 but it's ok if it's a null. However, I need that row because I need the name (`ename6`).

This is part of building a temp table in SQL Server if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```
insert @temp2(name, cost)
select ename6,
  sum(
    case when dqr.start_date >= @StartDate and dqr.start_date <= @EndDate then dqr.cost
    else 0 end
  )
from dbo.condensed7day_query_result dqr
group by dqr.ename6;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can filter using where condition as below:

```
insert @temp2(name, cost) 
  select ename6, sum(dqr.cost)
  from dbo.condensed7day_query_result dqr
  where dqr.start_date >= @startDate and dqr.start_date <= @EndDate
  group by dqr.ename6;
```

Comment: That does not work because the where clause is applied to everything and I no longer get all names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
insert @temp2(name, cost) 
Select ename6,cost from
( select ename6, IsNull(sum(dqr.cost),0) as cost
    from dbo.condensed7day_query_result dqr
    where (start_date >= @StartDate) and (start_date <= @EndDate)   
    group by dqr.ename6
) Temp
union 
(   Select ename6 , 0 as cost
    from dbo.condensed7day_query_result
    where ename6 not in ( 
    Select distinct ename6 
            from dbo.condensed7day_query_result dqr
            where (dqr.start_date >= @StartDate) and (dqr.start_date <= @EndDate)   
    )
)
```

In Sql you can use Whereclause before GroupByClause and so Aggregatefunction will work on resltset after Whereclause.
Also you can use Isnull function to return 0 value when the result of Sum is null. And the second Select returns the records that not exists in @StartDate and @EndDate range.